# Difference between two C snippets

Tags: c

I am at a loss to explain why these two C snippets do not behave the same way.  I am trying to serialize two structs, eh and ah, as a single buffer of bytes (uint8_t).  The first code block works, the second does not.  I can't figure out the difference.  If anyone can explain it to me it would be greatly appreciated.

**Block 1:**

```
uint8_t arp_reply_buf[sizeof(eh) + sizeof(ah)];
uint8_t *eh_ptr = (uint8_t*)&eh;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(eh); i++)
{
    arp_reply_buf[i] = eh_ptr[i];
}
uint8_t *ah_ptr = (uint8_t*)&ah;
int index = 0;
for (int i = sizeof(eh); i < (sizeof(eh) + sizeof(ah)); i++)
{
    arp_reply_buf[i] = ah_ptr[index++];
}
```

**Block 2:**

```
uint8_t arp_reply_buf[sizeof(eh) + sizeof(ah)];
arp_reply_buf[0] = *(uint8_t *)&eh;
arp_reply_buf[sizeof(eh)] = *(uint8_t *)&ah;
```

Comment: The second "does not work"? What does it do instead of working?

Comment: Ah sorry.  The first code block produces the correct buffer while the second produces a different buffer that does not have one particular field in the correct place.  It seems to be offset somehow.

Comment: I have labelled them "Block 1" and "Block 2" since, for some reason, the post won't let me separate them into two separate code blocks.  I used the code block markup twice separated by an empty row and it combined them on me.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Its ok. Go check @Binyamin's answer below. I think he summed up your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example you only set the values in two indexes:

1. `arp_reply_buf[0]`:

   ```
   arp_reply_buf[0] = *(uint8_t *)&eh;
   ```
2. `arp_reply_buf[sizeof(eh)]`:

   ```
   arp_reply_buf[sizeof(eh)] = *(uint8_t *)&ah;
   ```

Comment: Ah, I thought the result would be that all of the following indices would be overwritten by the remainder of the struct.